# CakePHP Behavior, Component, or neither

Tags: cakephp, components, behavior

I'm new to cakePHP and trying to get my head around when something is best developed as a Model/Behavior or Controller/Component.
I have an athletics scheduling system where various types of data, such as Venues, Schools, and Divisions get assigned to Sports. Taking Venues as an example: Venue and Sport have a HABTM association. I will be building a tool which allows users to select a Sport, and in so doing, view the Venues assigned to the Sport (list A), as well as the Venues that have not been assigned to the Sport (list B). They can then delete assigned venues (from list A) or add unassigned venues (from list B). A pretty basic tool which I know how to code in PHP. I have several of these same "assignment" tools throughout the app, which is why I want to abstract out.

I originally thought of building a Component, allowing me to get the two lists, and perform the adds & deletes, but am now wondering whether I can fatten my Models by creating a Behavior. I'm just a little lost conceptually, and would appreciate any clarification.

Comment: This question may be more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ not a bad question, but it may be flagged as 'not the right type of question for Stackoverflow'

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I haven't used Code Review but just took a look. Great resource!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP has the "Fat models, skinny controllers" motto. Your models/behavior should do all the heavy lifting and take care of all data manipulations. What you explain definitely belongs in a a custom model function or behavior.